# X-based email for reading mail from cron jobs

Tags: email, software-rec

Can anyone give a recommendation for a simple X-based equivalent of mail / mailx for reading the mail I get from cron jobs?

Comment: Do you mean solely X-based or simply a GUI app?  If you need X-only, then ignore my answer below.

Comment: I want something very simple which can read the mail from cron jobs only.

Comment: Of course the easiest solution is to let cron send mail to a mail account that you already use, or let the local mailserver forward it to one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evolution is fine, but heavy. [Sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/) is simpler and doesn't use as many resources.

Comment: How can I read local mail with this?

Comment: OK I found it: Configuration / Common preferences / Receive / Tick on "Incorporate from local spool".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Evolution nor Sylpheed, Thunderbird also allow to get /var/mail mail. You just have to create a new account and choose "movemail" as account type. See [mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird%3aHelp_Documentation%3aCreating_an_Account#Creating_a_Movemail_Account) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) can be set up to read system mail.  When setting up an account, simply choose "Local Delivery" as the server type on the "Receiving Mail" portion of the setup.  Then, on that same page, set the "Path" to /var/mail/ or wherever your mail spool is.

The "Local Delivery" option will delete the mail from /var/mail/.  If you use the "Standard Unix mbox spool file" will not.

Whether or not you want to call Evolution "simple" is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell script that calls a command-line mail tool and then uses notify-send, (g)xmessage or zenity to display the individual messages.

Comment: That sounds a bit masochistic but maybe I will try it if sylpheed gets annoying.

Answer (score 0):

[exmh](http://www.beedub.com/cgi-bin/wiki.cgi/exmh)  is a rather lightweight X-windows front end for mh, that will quite easily read your local mailbox.