# Receive notification new messages localhost MAC OS?

Tags: scripting, macos, notifications

I need to receive notifications when my backup script is executed successfully.

First I tried to send an e-mail to Thunderbird on `localhost`, but newer version of Thunderbird does not have Unix mail spool to configure.

Is it possible to send the output of a command with mail to a GUI notification in screen?

Comment: Related: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/x-based-email-for-reading-mail-from-cron-jobs) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427136/can-i-read-var-mail-with-a-gui)